# tensorflow retrain.py equivalent golang

Tags: tensorflow, go, equivalent

I would like to know if there is any equivalent of [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) in golang.

Thanks for help

Comment: as far as I know, training is supported only from python

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: Seems that this blog covers it:
https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/go/2020/11/27/deploy-train-tesorflow-models-in-go-human-activity-recognition/

Comment: @Adrian they are not asking for a recommendation, just if it is possible to train a tensorflow model using Go.